# Javascript getElementsByClassName only after inspect

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm working on a script to append an element to a added modal on a webpage.
The problem is that my `getElementsByClassName`method returns empty(edited) on run, but something after I inspect the page.

```
$('.my-trigerring-modal-button').click(function () {
   //try to avoid retrieve before modal added
    setTimeout(function() {
        var element = document.getElementsByClassName('Modal-form');
        if(element === undefined || element.length == 0){
            //always return undefined on run
            return;
        }
    }, 5000);
})
```

But when I run the code below in the browser console after inspect the page I retrieve the wanted elements

```
document.getElementsByClassName('Modal-form')
```

**EDIT**

Here is my code
HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="my-trigerring-modal-button" style="visibility: visible;"></button>
```

This HTML Button exists, also the 'Modal-form' element is added by a library script that I've no power on it.
For people who asked me if 5 seconds is enough: Yes! The `'Modal-form'` element is right shown before 5s.

*I'll not have asked you this if I wasn't  sure!*

My worry is that the library script stop my script to override his form but Chrome has enough right to do so after inspecting

Thanks

Comment: This is impossible to answer? How would we know where, and if, the element with a class of `Modal-form` exists? Also `getElementsByClassName` generally doesn't return `undefined`

Comment: It probably means that dom hasn't loaded yet. And you might want to wait for the element to exist.

Comment: @RudraniAngira - you'd think five seconds was enough?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. Also, if you're using jQuery, why aren't you *using* jQuery?

Comment: @adeneo It should be enough but no other reason seems plausible according to code.

Comment: Why are you using `getElementsByClassName` when you're clearly using jQuery too? Wouldn't it be best to stick with jQuery?

Comment: My bad `getElementsByClassName` not returns undefined but empty. the element is shown far before 5 seconds, I tried many ways to resolve this issue that's why mixing jQuery and javascript

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be coming from the fact that the element may not have been loaded yet. Use the onclick="" instead;

```
<a onclick="stackOverflow()"></a>
```

I also used raw javascript alone

```
function stackOverflow() {
    //try to avoid retrieve before modal added
    setTimeout(function() {
        var element = document.getElementsByClassName('Modal-form');
        if(element === undefined || element.length == 0){
            //always return undefined on run
            return;
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Although I dont know why you are using 5000ms it seems quite long.